# C# : this in method declaration

Tags: this

I came across a code section where the method declaration is as shown below;

```
   public MethodName(
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_Message> param1,
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_User> param2,
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_Directory> param3,
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_MessageInDirectory> param4,
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_Conversation> param5,
        ISessionAwareRepo<MCC_MessageRecipient> param6)
        : this(null, param1, param2, param3,
        param4, param5, param6)
```

I do not understand what does **:this** stand for in the method declaration. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called constructor chaining.

There is an overload of the constructor within the same class - the parameters are being passed in to the overload (so it gets executed before the body of the declaring constructor).

See [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 5):

In a constructor declaration, `: this()` calls another constructor of the same class that matches the given method signature, before the body of the current constructor is executed.